# Javascript for radio group

Tags: javascript

I have used a javascript to check if radio button is checked or not. If it is not checked than I return false. But my Js is not working for that...

```
       //Gender
if ((document.addpcpform.gender[0].checked == false) && (document.addpcpform.gender[1].checked == false)) {
    alert("Please choose your gender: Male or Female");
    return false;
}
```

Form name = `addpcpform.`, radio button name = `gender`.

If I use Id of radio at place than also it fails to run.

```
       //Gender
if ((document.addpcpform.Male.checked == false) && (document.addpcpform.Female.checked == false)) {
    alert("Please choose your gender: Male or Female");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Could you give your HTML code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if (!document.getElementById('Male').checked && !document.getElementById('Female').checked) {
   alert("Please chosse your gender: Make or Female");
   return false;
}
```

You can see more information at [How can I check whether a radio button is selected with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423777/how-can-i-check-if-a-radio-button-is-selected-in-javascript,which) is a possible duplication

Comment: If I wish to achieve task using getByName.. Because here I have only 2 radio group If I have more than 50 with name as `radio[]`?

Comment: If you have to validate multiples checkboxes, you just need to loop through them and check if at leat one is checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementsByName()` method which return a nodeList.

```
<form name="addpcpform">
 Male <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"/>
 Female <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"/>
...
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var gender=document.getElementsByName("gender");
alert(gender.item(0).checked + " " + gender.item(1).checked);
```