# Frustratingly simple Javascript Help Required

Tags: javascript, forms, show-hide

I am making a form field where I would like to do a simple show-hide to display div's on a radio button.

```
<form id="basic" name="basic">

<label><input name="formelement" type="radio" value="yes" /> Yes   </label>
<label><input name="formelement" type="radio" value="no" /> No </label>

<div id="yes" style="display: none;">
This is the div that displays that shows when 'Yes' is selected.
</div>

<div id="no" style="display: none;">
This is the div that displays that shows when 'No' is selected.
</div>

</form>
```

I have played with some various javascript's I have found online and have achieved not a lot of success as most of them online manage to show-hide one div. Getting the 'yes' to hide when 'no' is selected and vice-versa is the tricky part. If anyone could provide some assistance that would be really appreciated!

Comment: you may want to use JQuery. Take a walk-through at their tutorial, you will be able to do that with much ease http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

Comment: W3Schools is not regarded as one of the best places to learn JavaScript / jQuery (see http://W3Fools.com). A well-respected alternative for JavaScript is MDC's JavaScript Guide (http://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) . For jQuery, check out jQuery's documentation (http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just paste these code  between head tags

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
    var el1 = document.getElementsByName('formelement')[0];
    var el2 = document.getElementsByName('formelement')[1];  
    el1.onchange=function(){
        var show=el1.value;
        var hide=el2.value;
        document.getElementById(show).style.display='block';
        document.getElementById(hide).style.display='none';
    }

    el2.onchange=function(){
        var show=el2.value;
        var hide=el1.value;
        document.getElementById(show).style.display='block';
        document.getElementById(hide).style.display='none';
    }  
}
</script>
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/GZ6vL/)

Answer (score 0):

The below is assuming value of radio is same as id of the div..

```
function getRadioVal(name){
   var oRadio = document.forms[0].elements[name];
   for(var i = 0; i < oRadio.length; i++)
      if(oRadio[i].checked)
         return oRadio[i].value;
   return '';
}

//hide both divs..
document.getElementById("yes").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("no").style.display = "none";

//show only one of them..
document.getElementById(getRadioVal("formelement")) = "block";
```

---

Dealing with javascript without any libraries is a pain when things get complex, I would recommend libraries such as [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com)

Answer (score 0):

this is what you want

[How can I check whether a radio button is selected with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423777/how-can-i-check-if-a-radio-button-is-selected-in-javascript)

assign onclick event and you are good to go.