# check if a radiobutton is checked or not in struts2

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

i have an image tag in struts2. i want to check if a radiobutton is checked or not as its onclick() event..pls help me.

image tag:

```
<input type="image" src="../image/edit.jpg" alt="img" width="25" height="25"  value="Edit" name="moduleMenu"/>
```

radiobutton:

```
<s:iterator status="stat" value="modNameList">
                  <s:radio list="moduleName" name="modNameCheck" id="modNameCheckId"/>
                  <br>
                </s:iterator>
```

Comment: do you want to checked it on Server side or on Client side ?

Comment: You want to check the radio buttons status onclick of image tag or radio button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Example may help you :

```
var moduleNameRadio=document.getElementsByName("modNameCheck");

for(var i=0;i<moduleNameRadio.length;i++)
{
       if(moduleNameRadio[i].checked){
          alert('Radio button selected');
          //Add your code here....
      }
}
```

You can find more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423777/how-can-i-check-if-a-radio-button-is-selected-in-javascript) !

Answer (score 1):

```
<s:iterator status="stat" value="modNameList">
                  <s:radio list="moduleName" name="modNameCheck" id="modNameCheckId" onclick = "validate(this.value)" />
                  <br>
                </s:iterator>

<script>
function validate(value){
alert(value); 

}

</script>
//or u can pass this.id 

<s:iterator status="stat" value="modNameList">
                  <s:radio list="moduleName" name="modNameCheck" id="modNameCheckId" onclick = "validate(this.id)" />
                  <br>
                </s:iterator>

<script>
function validate(id){
alert(id);

}
```