# How to know which radio is checked from a fieldset

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have the following code:

```
    <fieldset id="dificuldade">
        <legend>Dificuldade:</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="dificuldade" value="facil"> Fácil </input>
        <input type="radio" name="dificuldade" value="medio"> Médio </input>
        <input type="radio" name="dificuldade" value="dificil"> Difícil </input>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="tipo">
        <legend>Tipo de jogo:</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="Tipodejogo" value="somar"> Somar </input>
        <input type="radio" name="Tipodejogo" value="subtrair"> Subtrair </input>
        <input type="radio" name="Tipodejogo" value="dividir"> Dividir </input>
        <input type="radio" name="Tipodejogo" value="multiplicar"> Multiplicar </input>
    </fieldset>

    <input type="button" value="Começa" id="button" ></input>
</form>
```

and here is the jsfiddle with both the html and the js http://jsfiddle.net/3bc9m/15/ . I need to store the values of the 2 fieldset so I, depending on the values picked can generate a game, but my javascript isn't returning any of them. What is wrong? I've been told that JQuery is much easier but i can't use it.

Comment: What Javascript do you speak of?

Comment: the Javascript code that is on this http://jsfiddle.net/3bc9m/15/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code on jsFiddle seems to be working fine for the most part.  The only thing was that the elements `output` and `output2` don't exist on the page.

So this code that was supposed to display the selected values wasn't working:

```
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = curr.value;
document.getElementById('output2').innerHTML = tdj.value;
```

The part that actually retrieves the selected values is working fine.

Just add those two elements to the page, like this:

```
<p>Selected Values:</p>
<div id="output"></div>
<div id="output2"></div>
```

An updated jsFiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3bc9m/34/).

**EDIT**

If a radio button from only one of the sets is selected, the code fails.  You could use this code to find the selected values instead:

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {

    var dif = document.getElementsByName('dificuldade');
    var tip = document.getElementsByName('Tipodejogo');

    var difValue;
    for (var i = 0; i < dif.length; i++) {
        if (dif[i].type === "radio" && dif[i].checked) {
            difValue = dif[i].value;
        }
    }

    var tipValue;
    for (var i = 0; i < tip.length; i++) {
        if (tip[i].type === "radio" && tip[i].checked) {
            tipValue = tip[i].value;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = difValue;
    document.getElementById('output2').innerHTML = tipValue;
};​
```

An updated jsFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3bc9m/32/).

Comment: You're code is working fine on the jsfiddle, but it isn't showing up on my page, it just shows "Selected Values:" and doesn't print any of the output values. I am only allowed to use 1 page, so i've been using DOMTAB : http://onlinetools.org/tools/domtabdata/ to alternate between tabs, is it the reason for why i'm not getting any output?

Comment: @Cláudio: I wouldn't think that DOMTab would be causing a problem, but it's hard to say for sure.  Running a debugger on it might give you some insight.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3bc9m/42/ I've tried changing your code so it gives an error when i don't choose both options, but seems like it shows the alert even if i pick both. I've never used a debugger, which one should i use?

Comment: @Cláudio: It was showing the alert even when you picked both because of a typing error.  This one should work: [http://jsfiddle.net/3bc9m/43/](http://jsfiddle.net/3bc9m/43/).  For the debugger, if you're using Chrome, use the Chrome developer tools that come with it (press shift+ctrl+i, and then go to the Sources tab).  For FireFox, FireBug is a good option.  If you're using IE, the IE developer tools will work fine (press F12).  It's really up to you which one you use.  I use the Chrome developer tools most of the time.

Comment: I tried using Firebug, but i was kind of lost, so I decided to download chrome and it gave me this "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null "

Comment: @Cláudio: Ah, I think I know what's going on.  Is your script at the top of the page?  If yes, either wrap the whole click handler in `window.onload = function() { // click handler here };` or move the script to the bottom of the page, right before the closing `</body>` tag.  For reference, if you are able to use jQuery in the future, use `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` or `$(function() { ... });` instead.

Comment: Yes it was at the top of the page, I've now used window.onload = function () and it is working. I now have the 2 output, since I'll have to use them in new functions, for example for each combination i will have to call a different function, how can i insert them in the newly created functions? And thanks for your help and patience, I've been trying to create this function for pratically a day and you just saved my life

Comment: @Cláudio: Just use a combination of `if` and `else if` statements, and call your external functions where appropriate.

Comment: do you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/AD8gr/2/ , also how do i make the game show up in that div once the player picks the game type and difficulty? DOMTAB needs to have a list so it can work, i've included that list here, I don't know if I am making myself clear

Comment: @Cláudio: Yes, that's the idea.  I'm happy to help, but I think these questions have gone beyond the scope of the original question.  If you need more help, I would suggest starting a whole new question.

Answer (score -1):

Consider this post that adresses the issue.  It shows a few javascript methods as well as how you would use it in jQuery.

[How can I check whether a radio button is selected with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423777/how-can-i-check-if-a-radio-button-is-selected-in-javascript)

Is there a specific reason you want to break it down by fieldset instead of directly accessing the radio buttons by name?

Comment: Not really, I'm just really confused and don't know where to start. The page you sent me is gold, thank you. I am using fieldsets for style purposes, i've edited and tried to call it by name and even have a var to see if it they are all selected but it's returning false every time: http://jsfiddle.net/3bc9m/35/