# javascript Validation gives me error alert even when all buttons checked

Tags: javascript, validation, radio-button

i have used this code to set a validation on a form to gives me alert when NOT all the buttons has checked! .. but when i try it , it gives me error alert even when all buttons checked .. help please ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm(formData){
    if(!this.v1.checked && !this.v2.checked && !this.v3.checked){
        alert('answer all questions please');
        return false;
    }
       return true;
    }
    </script>

    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="form1" action="mark.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post"> 
        <input type="radio" value="1" id="v1" name="v1"> <input type="radio" value="1" id="v2" name="v2"> <input type="radio" value="1" id="v3" name="v3"> <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look what is `this` refering to, using `console.log(this)`.

Maybe is better if you get the radio buttons using `getElementById()`, look an example here.

[How can I check whether a radio button is selected with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423777/how-can-i-check-if-a-radio-button-is-selected-in-javascript)

Also change the logic of your if statement, use this:

```
if (!document.getElementById('v1').checked || !document.getElementById('v2').checked || !document.getElementById('v3').checked)
```

I modified your script in jsfiddle.net, to make a working one:
http://jsfiddle.net/Xh5HW/1/

Comment: @user1806136, I think is a problem selecting the right element. It seems that you're not really checking the radio buttons in your if statement. Please review carefully the link above.

Comment: @user1806136, you have also a problem with the logic of the if statement. I added code you can use to my answer.

Comment: i hve used document.getElementById as u said it still doesnt work and also didn't give me alert box it just go to next page!

Answer (score 0):

```
var btn = valButton(form.group1);
if (btn == null) alert('No radio button selected');
else alert('Button value ' + btn + ' selected');
```

chek out http://javascript.about.com/library/blradio.htm