# Radio Button Validation HTML FORM

Tags: html, forms, validation, radio-button

I have this form:

```
<form name="form" action="order.php" method="post">
Please select Amount:<br />
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="25" id="25" /> <label for="25">$25</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="50" id="50" /> <label for="50">$50</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="75" id="75" /> <label for="75">$75</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="100" id="100" /> <label for="100">$100</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="200" id="200" /> <label for="200">$200</label><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I am wondering how I can do validate to make sure that one of these Radio Button's are selected?

I have tried a few different things, I have looked on Google and visited almost every site on the first and second pages and could not get it working..

Thanks,
Chad.

Comment: which language do you want to use for the validation? PHP? Java? Javascript? (not real validation in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution without using client-side scripting would be to select one by default using `CHECKED`:

```
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="25" id="25" CHECKED />
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLahW/) to show you.

If this won't work for your situation, look into using jQuery or Javascript to implement a solution.

This should help get you started:  [How can I check whether a radio button is selected with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423777/how-can-i-check-whether-a-radio-button-is-selected-in-javascript)

Good luck.