# showing content on selecting radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a scenario where I am showing different content on switching the radio button. it is working fine in chrome but not working in IE. Cant figure out what is going wrong.

```
<div id="Q6">
  <input type="radio" id="Q6A" value="yes" name="Q6"/>Same as current address<br/>
  <input type="radio" id="Q6B" value="no" name="Q6"/>New address<br/>
</div>

<div id="Q6Aoutput" style="display:none;">1</div>
<div id="Q6Boutput" style="display:none;">2</div>

<script>
$('#Q6').change(function(){
  if($('#Q6A').attr('checked')){
    $('#Q6Aoutput').show();
  }else{
    $('#Q6Aoutput').hide();
  }
  //
  if($('#Q6B').attr('checked')){
      $('#Q6Boutput').show();
  }else{
      $('#Q6Boutput').hide();
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: No, checked is correct.

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using? You probably need to be using `.prop` instead of `.attr`

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester, no. `selected` is for `<select>`

Comment: I would recommend getting the `checked` boolean property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
if($('#Q6A').attr('checked')){
```

With:

```
if($('#Q6A').prop('checked')){
```

And:

```
$('#Q6').change(function(){
```

You added a change event to the div, while it's valid as [events do bubble](http://jsfiddle.net/UVYEs/), I would have use this instead:

```
$('input[name="Q6"]').click(function(){
    $('#Q6Boutput').toggle(this.id == "Q6B");
    $('#Q6Aoutput').toggle(this.id == "Q6A");
});
```

Comment: Q6 is a DIV, not an input.

Comment: @Diodeus, I just commented on your answer, you're wrong, read my comment.

Comment: DAMNNNN @Diodeus Just got called out!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the [is(:selector)](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method of jQuery?
Also, it may be better to attach the event to the input radios directly.

```
$('#Q6A').change(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $('#Q6Aoutput').show();
  }else{
    $('#Q6Aoutput').hide();
  }
});
$('#Q6B').change(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
      $('#Q6Boutput').show();
  }else{
      $('#Q6Boutput').hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#Q6')` selects the `<div>`, not the `<input>`.

You could use `$('#Q6 input')`

Comment: But he did use `Q6A` and `Q6B`

Comment: `$('#Q6').change(function(){...` A div does not have a change event.

Comment: @idrumgood, events in javascript bubble, so the change event of the div does fire. I'm afraid your answer is wrong.

Comment: While technically you're correct (the best kind of correct) in his case with the issue being it not working in IE, this is why. The change event will not bubble in IE.

Answer (score 0):

There is a native javascript way to check it, see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1423783/1313143).

So in your case:

```
if($('#Q6A').checked){
    //etc
}
```

Comment: thats not native DOM, you would need to hit the DOM level `$(<SELECTOR>)[<INDEX>].checked`

Comment: Hi Matt, can you explain this little bit?

Comment: I was wrongly assuming that a jQuery object was constructed with all the element's native DOM properties. Just forgot it was always an array.