# Jquery detecting id of selected button?

Tags: jquery, button

Hi this is sending me around in circles.

Consider these radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" class="win" id="50" value="1" name="match1" />
<input type="radio" class="cover" id="50" value="2" name="match1" />

<input type="radio" class="win" id="51" value="1" name="match2" />
<input type="radio" class="cover" id="51" value="2" name="match2" />

<input type="radio" class="win" id="52" value="1" name="match3" />
<input type="radio" class="cover" id="52" value="2" name="match3" />
```

When the form is submitted I want to know the id of any of the buttons which are selected.

Some of the button pairs may not be selected at all.

I tried:

```
for (var x=1; x<4; ++x){

     if($('form #'+$(this).attr("id")+'input:radio[name=match'+x+']').prop('checked', true)){
          alert('Checked;);
     }

}
```

But it always evlautes to true.

Thanks

Comment: `id` attributes **need** to be unique ! (*and they should not start with a number unless you use html5*)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check whether a radio button is selected in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423777/how-can-i-check-whether-a-radio-button-is-selected-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the value to true. Remove the `,true` from the `prop` call:

```
if($('form #'+$(this).attr("id")+'input:radio[name=match'+x+']').prop('checked')){
      alert('Checked;);
}
```

When you set the property with `.prop('checked', true)` it returns the jQuery element that you called it on - and that evaluates to true.

Comment: I removed the true and now it always evaluates to be false!

Comment: Thanks! I had to remove the 'form id' and then it worked... so: if($('input:radio[name=match'+x+']').prop('checked'))

Answer (score 1):

You are `setting` the checked property in if instead of just `getting`

*Change*

```
if($('form #'+$(this).attr("id")+'input:radio[name=match'+x+']').prop('checked', true))
```

*To*

```
if($('form #'+$(this).attr("id")+'input:radio[name=match'+x+']').prop('checked'))
```

Comment: Can you show me where it is still deprecated in latest jQuery version?

Comment: No problem thanks for sharing the link and effort to help me, I will delete mine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will answer your question:

```
for (var i = 0, len = 4; i < len; i++) {
    if ( $('input[name=match' + i + ']:checked').val() ) {
        alert("Checked");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full working piece of code for your scenario, with example jsFiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/CV4x8/

```
<input type="radio" class="win" id="50" value="1" name="match1" />
<input type="radio" class="cover" id="50" value="2" name="match1" />

<input type="radio" class="win" id="51" value="1" name="match2" />
<input type="radio" class="cover" id="51" value="2" name="match2" />

<input type="radio" class="win" id="52" value="1" name="match3" />
<input type="radio" class="cover" id="52" value="2" name="match3" />

<button id="getChecked"></button>

function alertChecked() {
   for (var i = 0, x = 4; i < x; i++) {
       if ( $('input[name=match' + i + ']').is(':checked')) {
           alert("Checked");
        }
    }
}

$('#getChecked').click(function() {
    alertChecked();
});
```

Comment: This also worked thnaks. What is the difference between ".is(':checked')" and "prop('checked')" - should I use one over another

Comment: Not 100% sure in terms of efficiency, but I find it more readable, so I can look back on my code and figure out what's going on easier.

Comment: This is strange, the code works I can detect which radio buttons were checked. My script then clears all of the checked buttons that were previously checked. Then if I re-select some of the buttons and re-submit the form none are detected as being selected!

Comment: Ok I solved it and in doing so I think I have answered the question as to the difference between ".is(':checked')" and "prop('checked')". The later detected input that I had set by jquery. The former detected input when I had selected it by my mouse. Without the ".is(':checked')" the input was not detected if previously I had cleared any selected buttons with my script.

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use multiple ID's and don't start them with numbers cause it's no valid HTML.

```
$("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function( index ) {
     $('#output').append($(this).attr('id')+' is checked<br />');
});
```

Here is a jsFiddle that works in your case: http://jsfiddle.net/RGZH7/3/