# Show/Hide div on radio button selection does not work for some reason

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to get a div to show only when a radio button is checked but it doesn't work! It works when I set a value to it but I want it to show the div on refresh too so the value won't work for that.

Why does `if ($(this).attr("checked")) {` not work here?

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#dis_selection").change(function () {
         if( $('#dis_selection').val() == 1) { // if ($(this).attr("checked")) { doesn't work
             $('.hide_dis_slider').show();
          }
          else{
             $('.hide_dis_slider').hide();
          }         
     });
});
```

the radio button:

```
<input type="radio" name="dis" id="dis_selection" value="1" <?php echo $dis_check1; ?>>Local</label>
```

UPDATE:

```
 if(isset($_GET['distance']) && $_GET['distance'] === "1"){     
      echo '<li>Local</li>';    
      $dis_check1 = "checked";      
}
```

The div that is hidden until the checkbox is checked:

```
<div class="hide_dis_slider">blabla</div>
```

Comment: See if this popular question helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423777/how-can-i-check-whether-a-radio-button-is-selected-in-javascript

Comment: This didn't work for me that's why I asked. Not sure why the vote down. I searched everything before posting

Comment: how do i keep the div to show() on page refresh if it was selected before the refresh?

Answer (score 0):

The change event isn't fired on a radio button which gets **unchecked**, only when it is checked. When you click the other radio button, you aren't "changing" the first one (bit of a weird one). You can add classes instead, so it will monitor all your radio buttons, then you can decide what to do when specific radio buttons are checked/unchecked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".dis_selection_rb").change(function () {              
      if($("#dis_selection").is(':checked')) {
         $('.hide_dis_slider').show();
      }else{
         $('.hide_dis_slider').hide();
      }         
   });
});
```

So your HTML would be something like:

```
<input type="radio" name="dis" class="dis_selection_rb" id="dis_selection" value="1" checked>Local</label>
<input type="radio" name="dis" class="dis_selection_rb" id="dis_selection2" value="1">Not</label>

<div class="hide_dis_slider">Testing</div>
```

This JSFiddle shows it working: http://jsfiddle.net/wSxsp/

Note that you will need to add classes to your radio buttons, as it looks like you don't have any on them currently.

Comment: it doesn't work.. I tried that before. That's why I am asking here and not sure why I got a vote down for that

Comment: You didn't say you'd tried that. For the record I didn't vote your question down.

Comment: Although you need to give more information for people to be able to help. "It doesn't work" doesn't help anyone. What's in your PHP variable? Have you only got one radio button? If so, surely you'd be better using a checkbox? Etc.. give us some more code and a deeper background of your problem. There's plenty more HTML you could include (what you're trying to hide/show, etc).

Comment: I updated the code above. $dis_check1 is just a "checked". I did that for saving the selection made on the next visit to the website. I have 4 checkboxes total. I want specifically that checkbox only to slide a div out when it is selected.

Comment: I got it to work with if($(this).prop("checked")){ but it still does not hide if I select a different checkbox.. why?

Comment: I've just updated my answer. The change event isn't fired when a checkbox is unchecked, only when it is checked.