# Change label border when radio button selected in table

Tags: html, css

Ok I have an issue getting my label to change upon a radio button being selected.  The following code works just fine for what I need:

http://jsfiddle.net/8ypCV/

```
<table> not present
```

However, if I place the same code between table attributes like I need to, all of a sudden the code does not work.  I have tried giving the table a name/id/class and addressing the css to that but still nothing.  I just need to know what Im missing to get this code to work with in a table.
Here is the link to the fiddle with the table attribute:

http://jsfiddle.net/5g62v/
`<table> present`

Comment: Side note, `nowrap` isn't a valid attribute. Do you mean `white-space:nowrap`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working because your CSS uses the adjacent sibling selector (`+`) This means that only elements that are direct siblings will be selected. Try moving your `label` elements into the same table cell in order for your existing CSS to work.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dDVBq/

Comment: Thank you, yeah I found that out, however is there a work around if they are in different columns.  The only reason why I ask is because at work we have to use a program that creates certain html docs and there is no way to tell it to place them within the same td.  I would have to manually going into every file and remove the td separators on each row and each table.  Thats why I would either like to find a css work around or even a javascript work around that I can add in using a header file.

Comment: If you can use javascript then this should get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423777/how-can-i-check-whether-a-radio-button-is-selected-in-javascript

Comment: Ok looked through it, since Im not all that familiar with JS for this particular issue I went with something simple like:                  if $('input[id=T2_1]:checked') {'label[for=T2_1]'.border:2px.solid.red!important} this didn't work either would you be able to let me know what I might be missing in it?

Comment: @user258122 I'd post a new question for that