# prob with selected radio button using javascript?

Tags: javascript, radio-button

undefined output!! am i missing sth ? any idea ?

here is the radio button inputs :

```
  <tr> 
   <td>Yes <input type="radio" name="email"  id="email" value="yes"/></td> 
   <td></td> 
   <td>No <input type="radio" name="email" id="email" value="no"checked="checked"/></td> 
  </tr>



 <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="doIt()" style="width: 150px; height:30px" />


    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

       function doIt() {

          var emailopt = document.getElementById('email').checked.value;

        alert (emailopt);


    }
```

Comment: `var emailopt = document.getElementById('email').checked;` And you're not closing the `<script>` tag. Also, you have multiple `id`, which should be unique. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423777/javascript-how-can-i-check-whether-a-radio-button-is-selected

Comment: The "id" should be unique

Comment: Just comment the js function statement and put alert inside that, it is not working for that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have tried is completely wrong.  Instead use the below approach

1) Iterate through all the radio buttons with `name` property
2) Now using `checked` attribute, place an if statement and then extract the `value`

```
  function doIt() {
      var emailopt = document.getElementsByName('email');
      for (i = 0; i < emailopt.length; i++) {
          if (emailopt[i].checked) {
              alert(emailopt[i].value)
          }
      }
  }
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvs42/)

Comment: how should i grab the value ? which i can use it to add to url string or sth

Comment: @user3516668 have you checked the fiddle? it returns the value already.. can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
function doIt() {

          var emailopt = document.getElementById('email').checked;

        alert (emailopt);


    }
```

It will return true and false.
Lets me know if you have any questions.I hope it will help you.

Comment: its does return true or false but i wanted the value which is either Yes or No ...any addition to it?? thx