# How can I check if the returned value of a radio button is empty?

Tags: jquery

```
 return $('#attending_day_1 input[type=radio]:checked').val() = " "
```

I want to check if returned value is empty/radio button is unchecked. This is not working, what am I missing?

Comment: You're grabbing the elements that are checked. Why would you need to test if they are unchecked?

Comment: I wanted to use return and was wondering if there is a way to check if radio buttons are selected or not?

Comment: Could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423777/javascript-how-can-i-check-whether-a-radio-button-is-selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
return $('#attending_day_1 input[type=radio]').is(":checked");
```

Comment: Also if these are not checked?

Comment: Yes, if your selector returns a single element. is(":checked") checks your radio button is checked or not.

Comment: If you have multiple radio buttons and want to check any of them is selected, you can use as: return $('#attending_day_1 input[type=radio]:checked').length> 0 ;

Comment: Please share your full code with jsfiddle. So I can understand the problem.

Comment: okay so I need to validate, by checking if any one of the two groups of radio buttons is checked. Error if nothing is selected. All of these scripts work here, but I am not successful when I use && operators. For example:  return $('#attending_day_1 input[type=radio]:checked').length === 0  &&  $('#attending_day_2 input[type=radio]:checked').length === 0;}

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, I cannot use alert. I not to validate it by using depends?

Answer (score 1):

in javascript, = is assignment, == is a comparison operator. " " is a valid non empty string - try this:

```
'' === ' '
```

also, val() returns the value of the input element. if you want to check if none of the buttons are checked, see if the length of the jQuery selection is 0.

return ! $('#attending_day_1 input[type=radio]:checked').length

(note 0 is falsy, so !0 is true)

Answer (score 1):

As a function, the line below will return `true` if there are no checkboxes selected:

```
return $('#attending_day_1 input[type=radio]:checked').length === 0;
```

Comment: return $('#attending_day_1 input[type=radio]:checked').length === 0 && $('#attending_day_2 input[type=radio]:checked').length === 0;
can I do this as well?

Comment: Yes you can, but it's a bit wordy (and a long line). Rather than do that, it would make sense to use a class selector (rather than two ID selectors). For example: http://jsfiddle.net/MH4H8/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really like the class idea. But, I can't use alert. I need to show error on the page, can you show an example for displaying error when i validate rest of the page elements?. User has to select to come either on of the two days or both days. I display error if both days are unchecked. 
http://jsfiddle.net/pQNNU/