# Javascript getting information from radio buttons

Tags: javascript

So I have this:

```
<input type="radio" value="<10"> Less than 10 Bubbles
<br />
<input type="radio" value="10"> 10 Bubbles
<br />
<input type="radio" value="10"> More than 10 Bubbles

<br /><br />
<input type="button" onclick="CalculatePrice()" value="Calculate Price">
```

And basically I want to be able to do some code depending on what radio button is selected, how would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: define `code depending`.

Comment: Does [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423777/javascript-how-can-i-check-whether-a-radio-button-is-selected) help?

Answer (score 0):

```
      <script>
 function CalculatePrice()
{

If($(#radiobtn1).is(':checked'))
{
  var a=2+1;
  alert(a);
}
 If($(#radiobtn2).is(':checked'))
{
  //some code
}


 }


      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a `name` for each input:

```
<input type="radio" name="bubble" value="5"> Less than 10 Bubbles
<br />
<input type="radio" name="bubble" value="10"> 10 Bubbles
<br />
<input type="radio" name="bubble" value="30"> More than 10 Bubbles
<br />
<button onclick="getValues();">Get values</button>
```

Javascript to access the value of selected button:

```
function getValue(n) {
 var i, r = document.getElementsByName(n);
 for (i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
   if (r[i].checked) return r[i].value;
 }
 return '';
}

function getValues() {
 var g = getValue('bubble');
 alert(g);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery. just give the radio buttons a `class` attribute, and you're good to go with this basic script:

```
$('.radio-button-class-name').each(function(){
   $(this).click(function(){
      // Do stuff here
   });
});
```