# Javascript, get element by multiple condition (id and value)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I guess the problem is pretty simple but I couldn't find a solution anywhere. I want to check whether a radio button is checked or not. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1423783/1707938) a possible solution:

For these inputs

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender_Male" value="Male" />
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender_Female" value="Female" />
```

you can simply

```
if(document.getElementById('gender_Male').checked) {
  //Male radio button is checked
}else if(document.getElementById('gender_Female').checked) {
  //Female radio button is checked
}
```

Yet my inputs are like this:

```
<label><input id="16" type="radio" value="14" name="Q3"></input>Yes</label>
<label><input id="16" type="radio" value="15" name="Q3"></input>No</label>
```

`id` is not unique by itself but only in combination with `value`... How do I check whether Yes or No are selected?

Comment: `id`s should ALWAYS be unique. If there are duplicate elements with the same `id`, it's technically invalid HTML. So, you should give them different `id`s, and this problem's done

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m4acu2ce/

Comment: Based on your requirement, shouldn't your radio buttons have the same `name` rather than `id`s?

Answer (score 0):

As @Markasoftware said, `id` should always be unique. But browser still parse your html with the same `id`s.

So key point is that you can select an element without `id`.

Try `document.querySelectorAll` or `document.querySelector`. Here is code:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[value="14"]') // you can select all the `value='14'` inputs
document.querySelectorAll('input[name="Q3"]') // you can select all the `value='Q3'` inputs
```

You can compose these css3 selectors and reach your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the next selector:

```
$('input#16.14').is(':checked'){ 
    //YES is checked
}
$('input#16.15').is(':checked'){ 
    //NO is checked
}
```

But id should be unique.

Another way to check which one is selected it's using the input name:

```
$('input[name=Q3]:checked').val()
```

This way you will get `14` if YES is checked or `15` if No is checked

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the yes/no element is next element of your gender radio, you can try something like:

```
$('[name="gender"]').change(function(){

  if($(this).val() == 'Male'){

    $(this).next('input[type="radio"][value="14"]').prop('checked',true);

  }else{
   //Female

  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a  class to your radio buttons.

```
$('.radioGroup').change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == 'Male'){
      ///
  } else {
      //female
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
            <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
            <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        </head>

        <body>
   <label><input id="16" type="radio" value="14" name="Q3"/>Yes</label>
   <label><input id="16" type="radio" value="15" name="Q3"/>No</label>

         <script type="text/javascript">
            $('input[name=Q3]').change(function () {
                if ($('input[name=Q3]:checked').length > 0) {
                    var k = $('input[name=Q3]:checked').val();
                    alert(k);
                }
            });
        </script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(':radio').on('change',function() {
  if( this.checked && this.value === "14" ) {
    alert( "'Yes' was selected!" );
  } else if( this.checked && this.value === "15" ) {
    alert( "'No' was selected!" );
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input id="Q3_1" type="radio" value="14" name="Q3">Yes</label>
<label><input id="Q3_2" type="radio" value="15" name="Q3">No</label>
```