# How can I check if none of the radio buttons are checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two radio buttons, yes and no.

I want to check if any of the radio buttons are checked and if not, then default the no radio button to checked.

Here is my attempt:

```
if ($("#type_No").attr('checked', false) && $("#type_Yes").attr('checked', false)) {
    $('#type_No').attr('checked', true);
}
```

However, while testing this, I realized this is incorrect because it's setting the values of the checkboxes and not checking if they're checked or not.

So, how do I check if a radio button is checked or not based on the id of the radio button?

Comment: `$('#type_No, #type_Yes').is(':checked')`

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423777/javascript-how-can-i-check-whether-a-radio-button-is-selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$.is](http://api.jquery.com/is/) with selector `:checked`, like so

```
if (!$("#type_No").is(':checked') && !$("#type_Yes").is(':checked')) {
    // do something
}
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/tecixu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1):

I assume your radio buttons have a `name` property, so simply do:

```
var isChecked = $("[name='RADIONAMEHERE']:checked").length > 0
```

Comment: they don't have a name property, can I just use id?

Comment: @KalaJ -- Ehh.. then they aren't proper radio buttons. Can you select more than one at a time?

Comment: Provide same name to two radio buttons so that they becomes a group

Comment: opps sorry, you're right. They have a name. Thank you!