# form required patterns in html

Tags: html

How can i make it that its not allowed to choose Select (first option) from the dropdown:

```
<div>
    <label for="sc" accesskey="s">Scolarship</label>
    <select name="sc" id="sc" required="required">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option value="1">No</option>
        <option value="2">Yes</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use two radiobuttons instead?

Comment: @kingkero your actually right.

Comment: The required attribute is not supported in any major browser. So either use a radiobutton as @kingkero sugests, or make some validation in JavaScript. I'll choose the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way to set `disable` attribute your first option of `select` element

```
//HTML FORM EXAMPLE
    <form action="#" method="post">
<div>
        <label for="sc" accesskey="s">Scolarship</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <select name="sc" id="sc" required="required">
            <option value="0" disabled="disabled" >Select</option>
            <option value="1">No</option>
            <option value="2">Yes</option>
        </select>
    </div> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

//JS CODE

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    if ( document.getElementsByName('sc')[0].value == 0 ){
        alert('Select something !');    
    e.preventDefault();
    }else{
    alert("form is perfect");
    } 
});
```

See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8oswdnLo/2/

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent 'select' from been chosen in one of the following ways:
1. Remove the option value from it
2. Using Javascript and
3. disabling it

### REMOVE THE OPTION VALUE

If the code is rewritten as:

```
    <label for="sc" accesskey="s">Scolarship</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <select name="sc" id="sc" required="required">
        **<option>Select</option>**
        <option value="1">No</option>
        <option value="2">Yes</option>
    </select>
```

This will prevent the select option from being submitted with a value, then you can catch this error by throwing an error message due to empty submit value upon validation

### USING JAVASCRIPT (JQuery In particular)

You can use javascript to prevent the select option from been selected as in:

```
 <script>
     $(function(){
       $("#sc").on("change", function(){
       var val=  $("#sc").val();
       if (val == 0)
       {
          //Tell the user that the select option can't be selected then change it to 'no'
         $("#sc").val(1);
       }
     });
   });
 </script>
```

### DISABLING THE SELECT OPTION

The third available option and the least advisable is to disable it using the 'disable keyword':

```
<label for="sc" accesskey="s">Scolarship</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <select name="sc" id="sc" required="required">
        **<option value="0" disabled>Select</option>**
        <option value="1">No</option>
        <option value="2">Yes</option>
    </select>
```

The downfall of using this method is that the 'select option' is selected immediately the form is loaded it is very possible that the user submits the form immediately it finishes loading without selecting any option leaving the 'select option' has the submit value.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `disabled` attribute, i.e. `<option value="0" disabled>Select</option>`. However, since it is the default option, it will be initially selected anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave first option empty and on submit, you can check if there are any option selected or not. Ir you can check even with `Select` string.

Comment: Im a beginner, could you go throught it with me? i made the first option empty but now when i submit the form, it works even though i have chosen the option which is empty.

Comment: First check the other answer and check if you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```html
<div>
        <label for="sc" accesskey="s">Scolarship</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <select name="sc" id="sc" required="required">
            <option disabled="disabled">Select</option>
            <option value="1">No</option>
            <option value="2">Yes</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: works but if i don't choose anything and keep it at select , the form submits anyways which is incorrect.

Comment: You will need JS for that, which will check if there's no valid value selected then don't submit

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, it might make more sense to use radiobuttons instead of a select.

```
<div>
    <label for="sc" accesskey="s">Scolarship</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="sc" value="1"> Yes
    <input type="radio" name="sc" value="2"> No
</div>
```

Now there is no `select` option anymore that mustn't be selected.

Comment: yes but i have tried it, at first none is selected when i submit the form it submits which is incorrect. It should require one of them chosen. should i check one of them?

Comment: @Sam You will need to write some logic for that (possibly in JavaScript). There are [answers like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423777/javascript-how-can-i-check-whether-a-radio-button-is-selected) showing you how to check if a radio button is selected