# how to know which radio button is selected out of all options?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I am having a list of questions and for each question having 4 options. Now I want to know, which radio button is checked ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423777/how-can-i-check-whether-a-radio-button-is-selected-with-javascript?rq=1

Comment: What you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the radio buttons have ids you could use:

```
if (document.getElementById('radioId').checked){
    //do something
}
```

If you have loads of them you could use:

```
var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName('radioButtonName');
```

To get all the radio buttons that have that name field and then loop through them all with a for loop with an if statement to see if they are checked inside.

```
for(i=0;i<radioButtons.length;i++){
    if(radiobutton[i].checked){
        //do something
    }
}
```