# disable submit button for unchecked radio not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, disabled-input

I am trying to disable submit button for form till all fields are entered...

It is working for other field types...**BUT NOT FOR RADIO**

Even though we didn't check radio, Submit button gets ENABLED....

current code and jsfiddle as follows

```js
var inputs = $("form#myForm input, form#myForm textarea, form#myForm checkbox, form#myForm select");

var validateInputs = function validateInputs(inputs) {
      var validForm = true;
      inputs.each(function(index) {
        var input = $(this);
        if (!input.val() || (input.type === "radio" && !input.is(':checked'))) {
          $("#register").attr("disabled", "disabled");
          validForm = false;
        }
      });
      return validForm;
    }


    inputs.each(function() {
      var input = $(this);
      if (input.type === "radio") {
        input.change(function() {
          if (validateInputs(inputs)) {
            $("#register").removeAttr("disabled");
          }
        });
      } else {
        input.keyup(function() {
          if (validateInputs(inputs)) {
            $("#register").removeAttr("disabled");
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

```css
.link-button-blue {
  font: bold 14px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #002633;
  padding: 10px 16px 10px 16px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -o-border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.link-button-blue:disabled {
  font: bold 14px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 16px 10px 16px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -o-border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: no-drop;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <input type="submit" value="Go To Step 2" id="register" class="link-button-blue" disabled="disabled">
  </div>
<br><br>
<label for="mr"> <input type="radio" name="title" value="Mr" id="mr" /> Mr.</label><br />
<label for="mrs"> <input type="radio" name="title" value="Mrs" id="mrs" /> Mrs.</label><br />
<label for="miss"> <input type="radio" name="title" value="Miss" id="miss" /> Miss</label><br />
<label for="ms"> <input type="radio" name="title" value="Ms" id="ms" /> Ms.</label><br />
<label for="dr"> <input type="radio" name="title" value="Dr" id="dr" /> Dr.</label><br />
<br><br>
  <div class="form-field-label">Full Name :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <input type="text" value="" name="fname" id="fname" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-field-label">Address :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <textarea value="" name="address" id="address" rows="4" pattern=".{15,}" required title="15 characters minimum" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-field-label">Email :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <input type="text" value="" name="email" id="email" required>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-field-label">Mobile :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="12" minlength="10" name="mobile" id="mobile" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" required>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-field-label">Phone :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <input type="text" value="" name="phone" id="phone" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-field-label">Fax :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <input type="text" value="" name="fax" id="fax" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)">
  </div>

  <div class="form-field-label">Birthdate :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <input type="text" name="birthdate" id="birthdate" placeholder="Click To Open Calendar" required>
  </div>


  <br>
  <div class="form-field-label">Age :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <input type="text" value="" name="age" id="age" placeholder="Select Birthdate" required>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-field-label">Select Questionnaire Catagary :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input id="select_question_category-0" type="checkbox" name="select_question_category[]" value="General" /> General </label>
    <br>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input id="select_question_category-1" type="checkbox" name="select_question_category[]" value="Stressfull Life Like - IT/BPO/Management" /> Stressfull Life Like - IT/BPO/Management </label>
    <br>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input id="select_question_category-2" type="checkbox" name="select_question_category[]" value="Heredity of Cancer/Presently Suffering from Cancer/Suffered from Cancer" /> Heredity of Cancer/Presently Suffering from Cancer/Suffered from Cancer </label>
    <br>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input id="select_question_category-3" type="checkbox" name="select_question_category[]" value="Heredity of Diabetes/Presently Suffering from Diabetes" /> Heredity of Diabetes/Presently Suffering from Diabetes </label>
    <br>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input id="select_question_category-4" type="checkbox" name="select_question_category[]" value="Heredity of Heart Disease/Detected IHD/Suffered from Heart Attack" /> Heredity of Heart Disease/Detected IHD/Suffered from Heart Attack </label>
    <br>

  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-field-label">Gender :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <select name="gender" id="gender" required>
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="Male">Male</option>
      <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-field-label"></div>

</form>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vaidyamanishjoshi/7nbnt9bL/8/)

Comment: I guess this should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423777/how-can-i-check-whether-a-radio-button-is-selected-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

try this! hope it helps.
even though the submit button will be active. the form won't submit until all fields are filled out.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <input type="submit" value="Go To Step 2" id="register" class="link-button-blue">
  </div>
<br><br>
<label for="mr"> <input type="radio" name="title" value="Mr" id="mr" required /> Mr.</label><br />
<label for="mrs"> <input type="radio" name="title" value="Mrs" id="mrs" required /> Mrs.</label><br />
<label for="miss"> <input type="radio" name="title" value="Miss" id="miss" required /> Miss</label><br />
<label for="ms"> <input type="radio" name="title" value="Ms" id="ms" required /> Ms.</label><br />
<label for="dr"> <input type="radio" name="title" value="Dr" id="dr" required /> Dr.</label><br />
<br><br>
  <div class="form-field-label">Full Name :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <input type="text" value="" name="fname" id="fname" required />
  </div>
  <div class="form-field-label">Address :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <textarea value="" name="address" id="address" rows="4" pattern=".{15,}" required title="15 characters minimum" required /></textarea>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-field-label">Email :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <input type="text" value="" name="email" id="email" required />
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-field-label">Mobile :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="12" minlength="10" name="mobile" id="mobile" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" required />
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-field-label">Phone :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <input type="text" value="" name="phone" id="phone" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" required />
  </div>
  <div class="form-field-label">Fax :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <input type="text" value="" name="fax" id="fax" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" required />
  </div>

  <div class="form-field-label">Birthdate :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <input type="text" name="birthdate" id="birthdate" placeholder="Click To Open Calendar" required >
  </div>


  <br>
  <div class="form-field-label">Age :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <input type="text" value="" name="age" id="age" placeholder="Select Birthdate" required />
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-field-label">Select Questionnaire Catagary :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input id="select_question_category-0" type="checkbox" name="select_question_category[]" value="General" /> General </label>
    <br>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input id="select_question_category-1" type="checkbox" name="select_question_category[]" value="Stressfull Life Like - IT/BPO/Management" /> Stressfull Life Like - IT/BPO/Management </label>
    <br>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input id="select_question_category-2" type="checkbox" name="select_question_category[]" value="Heredity of Cancer/Presently Suffering from Cancer/Suffered from Cancer" /> Heredity of Cancer/Presently Suffering from Cancer/Suffered from Cancer </label>
    <br>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input id="select_question_category-3" type="checkbox" name="select_question_category[]" value="Heredity of Diabetes/Presently Suffering from Diabetes" /> Heredity of Diabetes/Presently Suffering from Diabetes </label>
    <br>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input id="select_question_category-4" type="checkbox" name="select_question_category[]" value="Heredity of Heart Disease/Detected IHD/Suffered from Heart Attack" /> Heredity of Heart Disease/Detected IHD/Suffered from Heart Attack </label>
    <br>

  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-field-label">Gender :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <select name="gender" id="gender" required />
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="Male">Male</option>
      <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-field-label"></div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.
It has a small bug though, when everything is valid, you have to update one of the inputs before the submit button will update.
Other than that, it works fine.

```js
var inputs = $("form#myForm input, form#myForm textarea, form#myForm checkbox, form#myForm select");

$(function() {
  var radVal = false;
  var validateInputs = function validateInputs(inputs) {
    var validForm = true;
    inputs.each(function(index) {
      var input = $(this);
      var inputType = $(this).attr('type');
      if (inputType === "radio" && input.prop("checked")) {
        radVal = true;
      }
      if (!input.val() || !radVal) {
        $("#register").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        validForm = false;
      }
    });
    return validForm;
  }


  inputs.each(function() {
    var input = $(this);
    var inputType = $(this).attr('type');
    if (inputType === "radio") {
      input.change(function() {
        if (validateInputs(inputs)) {
          $("#register").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
      });
    } else {
      input.keyup(function() {
        if (validateInputs(inputs)) {
          $("#register").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.link-button-blue {
  font: bold 14px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #002633;
  padding: 10px 16px 10px 16px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -o-border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.link-button-blue:disabled {
  font: bold 14px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 16px 10px 16px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -o-border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: no-drop;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <input type="submit" value="Go To Step 2" id="register" class="link-button-blue" disabled="disabled">
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <label for="mr">
    <input type="radio" name="title" value="Mr" id="mr" />Mr.</label>
  <br />
  <label for="mrs">
    <input type="radio" name="title" value="Mrs" id="mrs" />Mrs.</label>
  <br />
  <label for="miss">
    <input type="radio" name="title" value="Miss" id="miss" />Miss</label>
  <br />
  <label for="ms">
    <input type="radio" name="title" value="Ms" id="ms" />Ms.</label>
  <br />
  <label for="dr">
    <input type="radio" name="title" value="Dr" id="dr" />Dr.</label>
  <br />
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="form-field-label">Full Name :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <input type="text" value="" name="fname" id="fname" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-field-label">Address :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <textarea type="txtbx" value="" name="address" id="address" rows="4" pattern=".{15,}" title="15 characters minimum" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-field-label">Email :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <input type="text" value="" name="email" id="email" required>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-field-label">Mobile :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="12" minlength="10" name="mobile" id="mobile" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" required>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-field-label">Phone :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <input type="text" value="" name="phone" id="phone" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-field-label">Fax :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <input type="text" value="" name="fax" id="fax" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)">
  </div>

  <div class="form-field-label">Birthdate :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <input type="text" name="birthdate" id="birthdate" placeholder="Click To Open Calendar" required>
  </div>


  <br>
  <div class="form-field-label">Age :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <input type="text" value="" name="age" id="age" placeholder="Select Birthdate" required>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-field-label">Select Questionnaire Catagary :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input id="select_question_category-0" type="checkbox" name="select_question_category[]" value="General" />General</label>
    <br>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input id="select_question_category-1" type="checkbox" name="select_question_category[]" value="Stressfull Life Like - IT/BPO/Management" />Stressfull Life Like - IT/BPO/Management</label>
    <br>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input id="select_question_category-2" type="checkbox" name="select_question_category[]" value="Heredity of Cancer/Presently Suffering from Cancer/Suffered from Cancer" />Heredity of Cancer/Presently Suffering from Cancer/Suffered from Cancer</label>
    <br>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input id="select_question_category-3" type="checkbox" name="select_question_category[]" value="Heredity of Diabetes/Presently Suffering from Diabetes" />Heredity of Diabetes/Presently Suffering from Diabetes</label>
    <br>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input id="select_question_category-4" type="checkbox" name="select_question_category[]" value="Heredity of Heart Disease/Detected IHD/Suffered from Heart Attack" />Heredity of Heart Disease/Detected IHD/Suffered from Heart Attack</label>
    <br>

  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-field-label">Gender :</div>
  <div class="form-field-input">
    <select type="dropdown" name="gender" id="gender" required>
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="Male">Male</option>
      <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-field-label"></div>

</form>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wd2shmv2/)