# How to code buttons show and hide of 3 choices with identical id and name tags?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working with a form that have buttons with 3 choices - Expected; Unexpected; and No.  If you click on Expected or Unexpected, another question will appear.  If  you click on No, nothing will appear or will hide the question if it was showing.

I have been successful if I work with this form locally - no problem, as long as I use unique id tags for each button.  Unfortunately, this form need to be uploaded to a software that requires identical id and name tags for all the 3 choices, otherwise it will not upload.

I have tried different scenarios from using span trying to capture the value of the third option or capture the value of the first 2 options, etc. nothing seems to work.

Please anybody out there has an idea of how to do this:

[My code attempt is here on fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/IS2016/pgv5Ls76/1/)

I am using HTML and Javascript.

Thank you,

Irene

Update:

HTML Code:

```
 <div id="divHospitalization" class="fieldRow">
     <div class="leftLabel labelWidth12">
      <label for="txtHospitalization">Hospitalization:</label>
     </div>
     <div class="leftField">
      <div class="formField40"> 
        <input id="rbHospital" name="rbHospital" type="radio"
        class="radiobuttonfield" title="Hospitalization"
        value="Expected" onclick="javascript:HospitalOutcome();"
        />Expected
        <input id="rbHospital" name="rbHospital" type="radio"
        class="radiobuttonfield" title="Hospitalization"
        value="Unexpected"
        onclick="javascript:HospitalOutcome();" />Unexpected
        <input id="rbHospital" name="rbHospital" type="radio"
        class="radiobuttonfield" title="Hospitalization"
        value="No" onclick="javascript:HospitalOutcome();" />No
      </div> 
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="clearBoth"></div>
   <p></p>                       
   <div id="divHospOutcome" class="fieldRow" style="display:none">
    <div class="leftLabel labelWidth16">
      <label for="txtHospOutcome">Hospitalization Outcome:
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="leftField">
      <div class="formField40">
        <input id="rbHOutcome" name="rbHOutcome" type="radio"
        class="radiobuttonfield" title="Hospitalization Outcome"
        value="Admitted" />Admitted
        <input id="rbHOutcome" name="rbHOutcome" type="radio"
        class="radiobuttonfield" title="Hospitalization Outcome"
        value="NotAdmited" />Not Admitted/ER Only
      </div> 
    </div>
   </div>
```

Javascript code:

```
 function HospitalOutcome() {
   if (document.getElementById('rbHospital').value = "No") {

    document.getElementById('divHospOutcome').style.display = 'none';

   } else 

  {
     document.getElementById('divHospOutcome').style.display = 'block'; 

   }  
 }
```

Comment: As the system probably pointed out when you tried to post your link, you're required to show your code here.

Comment: ^^ as mentioned above, trying to work around SO by putting a link in a code block will only earn you down votes with a possibility of getting closed. The reason you should add your code is for others that may have the same problem as you, they might come across this question in the future but the link might no longer be any good which makes this question of no use to others in the future

Comment: In the past I put the code in here and I received the comment to use jsfiddle.  I am new to all of this.  I have no problem either way.

Comment: @IreneS If its a lot of code, it is a good idea to do both. However you should not just add a fiddle without the code. And BTW I removed my downvote

Comment: Thank you for the advice

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, IDs in HTML are supposed to be unique.

Ignoring that for now however, you can assign unique classes to the radio buttons and use `document.getElementsByClassName()` instead.

Like so:

```
<input id="rbHospital" name="rbHospital" type="radio"
        class="radiobuttonfield radio1" title="Hospitalization"
        value="Expected" onclick="javascript:HospitalOutcome();"
        />Expected
        <input id="rbHospital" name="rbHospital" type="radio"
        class="radiobuttonfield radio2" title="Hospitalization"
        value="Unexpected"
        onclick="javascript:HospitalOutcome();" />Unexpected
        <input id="rbHospital" name="rbHospital" type="radio"
        class="radiobuttonfield radio3" title="Hospitalization"
        value="No" onclick="javascript:HospitalOutcome();" />No
```

Edit: There seems to be a problem in JS Fiddle. The click handler can't be found for some reason. Stick this code in an html file and it should work just fine:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
  function HospitalOutcome(elem) {
      if (hasClass(elem, "radio3") && elem.checked) {
          document.getElementById('divHospOutcome').style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('divHospOutcome').style.display = 'block';
      }

      function hasClass(element, cls) {
          return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
      }
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="divHospitalization" class="fieldRow">
  <div class="leftLabel labelWidth12">
    <label for="txtHospitalization">Hospitalization:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="leftField">
    <div class="formField40">
      <input id="rbHospital" name="rbHospital" type="radio"
      class="radiobuttonfield radio1" title="Hospitalization"
      value="Expected" onclick="javascript:HospitalOutcome(this);"
      />Expected
      <input id="rbHospital" name="rbHospital" type="radio"
      class="radiobuttonfield radio2" title="Hospitalization"
      value="Unexpected"
      onclick="javascript:HospitalOutcome(this);" />Unexpected
      <input id="rbHospital" name="rbHospital" type="radio"
      class="radiobuttonfield radio3" title="Hospitalization"
      value="No" onclick="javascript:HospitalOutcome(this);" />No
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="clearBoth"></div>
<p></p>
<div id="divHospOutcome" class="fieldRow" style="display:none">
  <div class="leftLabel labelWidth16">
    <label for="txtHospOutcome">Hospitalization Outcome:
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="leftField">
    <div class="formField40">
      <input id="rbHOutcome" name="rbHOutcome" type="radio"
      class="radiobuttonfield" title="Hospitalization Outcome"
      value="Admitted" />Admitted
      <input id="rbHOutcome" name="rbHOutcome" type="radio"
      class="radiobuttonfield" title="Hospitalization Outcome"
      value="NotAdmited" />Not Admitted/ER Only
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not sure how to assign unique classes, please can you give me an example.  Thank you

Comment: Leo - I tried it, it did not work.  This is code I used:

Comment: if (document.getElementsByClassName('radio3').value = "No")

Comment: You don't check its value. You check whether it's checked or not with `.checked` instead. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423777/how-can-i-check-whether-a-radio-button-is-selected-with-javascript

Comment: I am sorry - it did not work -  if (document.getElementsByClassName('radio3').checked) {

Comment: Just FYI - I tried switching the class name to be first - class="radio3 radiobuttonfield"  doing this it shows but no matter which buttons you click - all three buttons shows the hidden question - when you click on the No it does not hide it.

Comment: Sorry Leo - it is not working - the first buttons work but they do not show the 2nd question when clicking on Expected and Unexpected.

Comment: I copy and pasted the code from an HTML file that worked. I don't know what's happening. I'm afraid you're on your own. It works for me.

Comment: getElementsByClassName always returns an array. You'll need to use document.getElementsByClassName('radio3')[0]

Comment: Just double checked. It didnt' work. It should work now.

Comment: Leo - I am sorry it took me this long to thank you for your help.  It worked beautiful your code.  It is exactly what I am looking for.  As long as I run the form locally, it works.  Unfortunately, when I upload the form to this software, it does not work.  The first level buttons work, what does not work is the show and hide of the 2nd level buttons.  I tried everything I could think of, no success.  I am not sure what to do. It does work on 2 buttons, the show and hide but not the 3 buttons choices.  Anyway, again thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @IreneS I'm afraid I can't help you with that since I don't have access to the software. You are more than welcome to ask a different question but as far as I'm concerned this question is answered. Good luck with the other problem.

Comment: The software that I must upload to is MasterControl - I am not sure if anyone out there knows MasterControl and if they have any idea if there is a trick to get this issue working.