# How to insert the value of dynamically radio button using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a html table, each table row have a radio button dynamically generated. Each option in the radio button have a unique id that generated dynamically also. But this id is not yet save in the database.

How to insert the option id? And how to update the option answer in that option id? Please help me. I tried to insert the values but I have no luck

Scenario:

There's a default value for the radio button, which is "No". When the user change the default value, there's a confirmation box that will ask the user if he/she want to processed. If the user click "Ok" the default value will change into "Yes".

PHP for html table:

```
    echo '<td id="resumeFile'.$optionId.'">' . $record_s->attachment_resume_id . '</td>';
    echo '<td id="processedYes><label for="Yes">Yes</label>
              <input type="radio" id="processedOptionYes'.$optionId.'" name="processedOption" value="Yes" onclick="proccessedCheck('.$optionId.',\'Yes\')"/>
              <label for="No">No</label>
              <input type="radio" id="processedOptionNo'.$optionId.'" name="processedOption" value="No" checked="checked" onclick="proccessedCheck('.$optionId.',\'No\')" echo $record_s->process_resume === "No" checked="checked"/>/>No</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
        }
    echo '</table>';
}

if (isset($_POST['optionId']) && $_POST['optionId']){
    $optionId = $_POST['optionId'];
    $queryOptionId = $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO resume_databank(process_resume_id) VALUES ('$optionId')");
}
```

Hidden Form:

```
<form id='hiddenForm' method='POST' action=''>
    <input type="hidden" id="inputHidden1" name="optionId" />
    <input type="hidden" id="inputHidden2" name="optionAnswer" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
function proccessedCheck(optionId,optionAnswer){
    if(optionAnswer == 'Yes'){
        if (confirm('You have chosen ' + optionAnswer + ', is this correct?')){
            jQuery("#processedOptionYes" + optionId).attr('disabled',true);
            jQuery("#processedOptionNo" + optionId).attr('disabled',true);
            var withlink = jQuery("#resumeFile"+ optionId).html();
            var withoutlink = jQuery(withlink).html();
            jQuery("#resumeFile"+optionId).html("").append(withoutlink);
            jQuery("#inputHidden1").val(optionId);
            jQuery("#inputHidden2").val(optionAnswer);
            jQuery("#hiddenForm").submit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First hidden filed changed to text box and check when radio button select, properly value placed the hidden filed

Answer (score 0):

I dont use Jquery, but Javascript is pretty simple to read the value.  It is the same as a checkbox value in that it is .checked when true.

Loop through your form fields looking for checked items

```
var formObj = document.getElementById('hiddenform');
for(var i = 0;i < formObj.elements.length;i++){
   radiovalues[] = escape(formObj.elements[id].checked);
}
```

Most fields have a value, ie text, hidden, password etc

```
escape(formObj.elements[id].value)
```

The checkbox and radio doesnt have a value, you are looking for "checked" which will return true or false.

Comment: so i will put that after the jquery function? so i will create a new function and call it in the hidden form?

Comment: This is where you have ` if(optionAnswer == 'Yes')`, your looking for the value, i would be looking for .checked.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423777/how-can-i-check-whether-a-radio-button-is-selected-with-javascript

Comment: `proccessedCheck(optionId)` and `if(optionId.checked)`

Answer (score 0):

Hi u can change the jquery by using like below with using a class instead of function in the input type, add a class radiods to input type= radio.

```
$(".radiods").click(function(){
    var clickid = this.id;
    if($('input:radio[name=processedOption]:checked').val() == "Yes")
    {
        if (confirm('You have chosen YES, is this correct?'))
        {
            $("#inputHidden1").val(clickid);
            $("#inputHidden2").val("Yes");
        }
    }
});
```

and then use ajax to update in database,so no need of form

Comment: do u require for ajax or above example

Comment: it's ok now :) i have a new question relevant with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37431587/cascade-dropdown-not-working-using-js/37431909?noredirect=1#comment62369831_37431909