# Alert if radios unchecked on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to check if a one of two radio buttons have been checked when submitting a form to validate before submitting.

```
<body onload="init();">
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm();">

    <label for="cName">Client Name*</label><br>
    <div style="width:74.8%; display:inline-block;">
            <input type="text" id="cName" name="cName" placeholder="Client Name..." required>
        </div><div style="width:25.2%; display:inline-block;">
            <select class="select1" id="cRecord" name="cRecord" required>
                <option value="" disabled selected>Advised Recording... 
                </option>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
        </div>

    Yes <input required type="radio" onclick="javascript:smeCheck();" value="Yes" name="TL/SME" id="yesCheck"> 
    No <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:smeCheck();" value="No" name="TL/SME" id="noCheck"><br>
    <div id="ifyes" style="display:none">

   <div class="buttons">
        <input type="button" id="formOut" onclick="this.form.submit();" value="Submit">      
    </div>

<script>
$('#formOut').click(function validateForm() {
  var Name = document.forms["myForm"]["cName"].value;
  var Record = document.forms["myForm"]["cRecord"].value;
  var yesSME = $("#yesCheck").prop("checked");
  var noSME = $("#noCheck").prop("checked");

  if (Name == "") {
  alert("//Alert Here");
  return false;
  }
  if (Record == "") {
  alert("//Alert Here");
  return false;
  }
  if (yesSME == false || noSME == false) {
    alert("//Alert Here");
    return false;
  } else if (cName != "" && cRecord != "" && ((yesSME == true) || (noSME == true))) {
    // do things here
  }
});
<script>
</form>
```

Currently I find with what I have above the user receives an alert upon form submission even when a radio option is selected.

Edit:

Desired behaviour - Upon the user clicking the "Submit" button if the fields `cName`, `cRecord` and one of the radios has been selected a Modal will open.

Current Behaviour -  When the user clicks the "Submit" Button if the fields `cName`, `cRecord` and one of the radios have been selected an alert is given for the radio buttons.

If one or both of the fields `cName` or `cRecord` have no user input when clicking the "Submit" button an alert is given for the cName or cRecord field.

The function (opening the modal) works without any issues if I remove the check for the radio button being checked,

The only issue seems to be with the check for if a radio button is selected/unselected

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check whether a radio button is selected with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423777/how-can-i-check-whether-a-radio-button-is-selected-with-javascript)

Comment: @chbchb55 I have made some edits to give some further context, from what I can see there isn't an example I can apply/get working from the solution linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** Another answer (I'd like to keep first one for reference)

you can achieve what you want like :

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form id="form1" action="javascript:void(0);">
 <label for="cName">Client Name*</label><br>
   <input type="text" id="cName" name="cName" placeholder="Client Name..."> <br><br>

  <select class="select1" id="cRecord" name="cRecord">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Advised Recording... 
                </option>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="No">No</option>
</select>
  <br>

  Yes <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="TLSME" id="yesCheck"> 
    No <input type="radio" value="No" name="TLSME" id="noCheck"><br>

  <input type="submit" id="formSubmit" value="Submit">  

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

JS (JQuery):

```
$("#form1").submit(function(){

    if (!$("input[name='TLSME']").is(':checked') || $("#cName").val() === '' || $("#cRecord").val() === '') {
   alert('Please complete required fields!');
} else {
    // your code here
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get this to work as I intended with your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked || !document.getElementById('noCheck').checked) {
    alert('Not checked');
}
```

Should do the trick

Comment: This gives the alert when unchecked but still gives an alert when an option has been checked when I use `else if((document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) || (document.getElementById('noCheck').checked))`

Comment: You don't need to do else if. Just use } else { and process the form in the else statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily using JQuery:

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>

<form id="form1" action="javascript:void(0);">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other <br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
 $("#form1").on("submit", function(){
   //Code: Action (like ajax...)
  if ($('input[name=gender]:checked').length <= 0) {
    alert("No radio checked")
}
 })
```

** Note:

```
action="javascript:void(0);"
```

was added to prevent form submission (do nothing), you can remove it when you have action to do.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, You solution while working with the two radios I can't seem to get working with the other variables I have, would you be able to advise how I could implement the solution to work with my edits above? Thank you

Comment: Please post your HTML and JS, so i can investigate

Comment: I have updated my post with a cutdown copy of the HTML to where should be relevant, Thank you

Comment: ok, your edit didn't say what you want your code to do, please explain in detail

Comment: My apologies, I have added the current and expected behaviour to my edit, The only issue I am having with the code is getting an alert if no radio is checked (and all fields have user input) and opening the modal if all fields have user input and a radio option is selected.

Answer (score 0):

### Why not make the radio buttons `required`

It would seem that you're trying to do the job of the browser. You don't need to display an alert, *which are generally bad UX*, because you can use built-in form validation via the `required` attribute like so:

```
<form onsubmit="...">
  <input type="radio" name="group" value="1" required />
  <input type="radio" name="group" value="2" />
  ...
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
<form />
```

**NOTE:** you only need one `required` attribute and it will apply to all inputs in said group.

Comment: This is something I have already done but the form submit is calling a function to open a Modal on the same page. using a `<submit>` just opens the Modal over the top of the page even when the `Required` fields are empty, I apologise I forgot to add this too my original question.

Comment: The `onsubmit` event should never even fire if you've set it up correctly @user10073459