# How to set selected value of radio buttons to a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a speed typing game. I also have a form with 3 radio buttons and i want to select the level of the game based on the selected radio button. How can i do that?

I've tried with `document.querySelector('input[name="genderS"]:checked').value;` this code here. But it doesn't worked

```
const levels = {
  easy: 5,
  medium: 3,
  hard: 1
};


let easyChecked = document.querySelector('#radio-easy').checked;
let mediumChecked = document.querySelector('#radio-medium').checked;
let hardChecked = document.querySelector('#radio-hard').checked;

var currentLevel = levels.medium;
let time = currentLevel;
let score = 0;
let isPlaying;

// To change level
function isChecked() {

}
```

I expect currentLevel variable to be changed based on the radio buttons.

Comment: You;ll need to post your HTML etc so people can help

Comment: Did you read this:? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423777/how-can-i-check-whether-a-radio-button-is-selected-with-javascript/1423852

Comment: I think your issue is that this code is running once at the beginning and then your checking the radio buttons and it's not updating like your expecting. For that you will need to listen for the event change.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
 var currentLevel = null;  // not set yet

 let easyChecked = document.querySelector('#radio-easy');
 let mediumChecked = document.querySelector('#radio-medium');
 let hardChecked = document.querySelector('#radio-hard');

 easyChecked.addEventListener("change", function() {
   currentLevel = this.checked; // update currentLevel on change
 }); 
 mediumChecked.addEventListener("change", function() {
   currentLevel = this.checked; // update currentLevel on change
 }); 
 hardChecked.addEventListener("change", function() {
   hardChecked = this.checked; // update currentLevel on change
 });
```

Now **currentLevel** will be updated when the radio buttons change.

Comment: Now it doesn't show the time in the html and only starts in a hard mode doesn't matter i select easy or medium

Answer (score 0):

Simply, make your radio button HTML code with the same name like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="level" value="easy"> Easy<br>
<input type="radio" name="level" value="medium"> Medium<br>
<input type="radio" name="level" value="hard"> Hard<br>
```

then bind all radio button with on `change` event by foreach loop

```
let selectedLevel;
const levelButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="level"]');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(levelButtons, function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('change', function(){
    selectedLevel = this.value;
    console.log(selectedLevel);
  });
});
```