# Run function if one radio input has been checked out of a group

Tags: javascript

I saw a similar question answered before, but they were too complicated for me to understand, i want a very easy way to do it, if thats possible.

So i have 6 radio inputs. I want a function to run when one of them (whichever) is checked.

html:

```
<input type="radio" id="AR" name="gun"> Assault Rifles <br>
<input type="radio" id="SMG" name="gun"> Submachine Guns <br>
<input type="radio" id="SG" name="gun"> Shotguns <br>
<input type="radio" id="LMG" name="gun"> Light Machine Guns <br>
<input type="radio" id="MR" name="gun"> Marksman Rifles <br>
<input type="radio" id="SR" name="gun"> Sniper Rifles <br> <br>
```

script:

```
var alleRadio = document.querySelectorAll("input");

if (alleRadio.checked === true) {}
```

(The `if` is inside a function that is started by a click)

As you might imagine this doesn't work, so what do I do?
I need super simple answers/solutions, as I am not the best in this, thank you :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check whether a radio button is selected with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423777/how-can-i-check-whether-a-radio-button-is-selected-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could go about this is to iterate through all radio buttons when the `div` element is clicked and see if any of them is `checked`.

Here's an example:

```js
var div = document.querySelector("div");

div.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // select all input elements with type of `radio` from the page
  var radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
  var checkedRadioButton = null;
  
  // iterate through all radio buttons that have been found
  for (var i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {   
    // save a reference to each individual radio button
    var radioBtn = radioButtons[i];
    
    // if a checked radio button hasn't been found yet and
    // the current radio button is checked, mark it as such
    // since we only care about just ANY checked button
    if (!checkedRadioButton && radioBtn.checked) {
      checkedRadioButton = radioBtn;
    }
  }
  
  // check if `checkedRadioButton` is not `null`
  if (checkedRadioButton) {
    // do whatever you need here, e.g. call a function
    myFunction(checkedRadioButton);
  }
  
  if (!checkedRadioButton) {
    console.log('select a random radio button and click again!');
  }
})

function myFunction(radioBtn) {
  // do whatever you need to do with that information here
  console.log(radioBtn);
  console.log('radioBtn.checked', radioBtn.checked)
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>Clicking on this DIV will trigger a `click` event!</div>

<input type="radio" id="AR" name="gun" /> Assault Rifles <br />
<input type="radio" id="SMG" name="gun" /> Submachine Guns <br />
<input type="radio" id="SG" name="gun" /> Shotguns <br />
<input type="radio" id="LMG" name="gun" /> Light Machine Guns <br />
<input type="radio" id="MR" name="gun" /> Marksman Rifles <br />
<input type="radio" id="SR" name="gun" /> Sniper Rifles <br />
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but this was too hard for me to understand. Greatly appreciated though!

Comment: @Grude What is confusing in this example?

Comment: 1 I dont understand how it works and i am not sure if thats what iam looking for. Is there really no easy way to do this, everything seems so hard :(

Comment: Could be that i just formed my question really bad and excluded a few stuff from my code. But its basically that i have a function that runs by clicking on a div, but inside this function i have this "if", that starts the animation and sound JUST when a random radio is clicked. If that made any sense.

Comment: @Grude I'd be helpful if you could provide an example that does exactly what you say. Clicking on a `div` doesn't trigger a select on a radio button, so you should still create event listeners for the `click` event on your radio buttons and do whatever you need when that event triggers.

Comment: I have event listeners and the function runs when i click the div, i just want the IF to run when one random radio box is checked, because if not, the animasjon and sound runs when its clicked.

Comment: @Grude have a look at my updated answer - hopefully this somewhat resembles the setup you have on your end.

Comment: I looked at it now, and i think you misunderstood me. Maybe i am just bad at explaining, but i really really do appreciate you trying and all the efforts you put into this, i just explain bad. I appreciate it like i said, but dont worry about making me understand it, help someone else that needs it more. Thank you anyways!

Comment: I just found an easy solution! if (AR.checked === true || SMG.checked === true || SG.checked === true || LMG.checked === true || MR.checked === true || SR.checked === true)

Comment: @Grude that's essentially what I am doing inside of that `for` loop - it makes it a lot easier to just do it that way so that you don't have to check those radio buttons individually and do the check manually.

Comment: Yes but i am really new to for loops and its hard to understand for me, your answer is probably perfect, its just that i dont understand it. But luckily what i did was super easy and it works (would suck if it was a lot of radio buttons, but for this project its okay), thank you for everything again!

Comment: Learnt more about for loops, and looked back at this, and it worked perfectly! But i just changed it to fit checkboxes instead. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here a sample

Hope it's help you.

app.js :

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.radio');

inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', (evt) => {
    if(evt.target.checked) {
      // Launch your function
      console.log('check');
  }
}));
```

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="radio" id="AR" name="gun" class="radio"> Assault Rifles <br>
    <input type="radio" id="SMG" name="gun" class="radio"> Submachine Guns <br>
    <input type="radio" id="SG" name="gun" class="radio"> Shotguns <br>
    <input type="radio" id="LMG" name="gun" class="radio"> Light Machine Guns <br>
    <input type="radio" id="MR" name="gun" class="radio">  Marksman Rifles <br>
    <input type="radio" id="SR" name="gun" class="radio"> Sniper Rifles <br> <br>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping! But found an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your attempt doesn't work is because [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a non-live [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

> ```
> var alleRadio = document.querySelectorAll("input");
> ```

The returned `NodeList` doesn't have the property `checked`. Instead you should check if one of the elements in the list is checked.

You can convert any [iterable object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) to an array using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from). You can then use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if at least one of the elements is checked.

```
const oneOrMoreChecked = Array.from(alleRadio).some(input => input.checked);
//     ^ true or false
```

Comment: Thank you for this! But i just figured out how to do it: if (AR.checked === true || SMG.checked === true || SG.checked === true || LMG.checked === true || MR.checked === true || SR.checked === true)

Comment: @Grude You don't have to specifically compare with `true`, the following would also work fine: `if (AR.checked || SMG.checked || SG.checked || LMG.checked || MR.checked || SR.checked)`

Answer (score 0):

Make a var of each radio input with document.querySelector("#ID")
Example:

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" id="AR" name="gun"> Assault Rifles
```

script:

```
var AR = document.querySelector("#AR")


if (AR.checked || SMG.checked || SG.checked || LMG.checked || MR.checked || SR.checked)
```