# can I change the value of boolean on clicking input field with type radio?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

How can I assign flag `true` or `false` while clicking on input field as:
In my `.ts` file:

```
 one:boolean=false;
 two:boolean=false;
```

In `.html` File

```
<div class="container">
   <label>Yes
      <input type="radio" id="one">
   </label>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <label> No
      <input type="radio" id="one">
   </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check whether a radio button is selected with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423777/how-can-i-check-whether-a-radio-button-is-selected-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Bind your radio button with `[(ngModel)]` will solve your problem.

Try this.

```html
<div class="container">
  <label>Yes
    <input type="radio" id="one" name="one" [(ngModel)]="one" value="true">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <label> No
    <input type="radio" id="one" name="one" [(ngModel)]="one" value="false">
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<p>
   <input type="radio" value="one" name="gender" [(ngModel)]="result" (ngModelChange)="setValues()" > One
   <input type="radio" value="two" name="gender" [(ngModel)]="result"  (ngModelChange)="setValues()" > Two
</p>
```

And in ts

```
one =true;
 two=false;
 result;

 setValues(){
  this.one =this.result === 'one' ? true :false;
  this.two =this.result === 'two' ? true :false;
 }
```