# how to check that the radio button

Tags: javascript, count, binding, svelte, sveltekit

I have to find that the radio button is checked or not if its clicked and checked then count will increase of its . And if count will increase then it will increase only one time. it will not increase on multiple click on same radio button in sveltekit.

[image]

Kindly suggest the count increment method on radio button

it will increase count when click and not increment count when multiple click on same radio button

Comment: Don't paste a screenshot. Please post with a minimum reproducible code.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 0):

I think the knowledge you are missing is likely how to determine if the radio is checked? If so, the top answer to this provides a good explanation: [How can I check whether a radio button is selected with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423777/how-can-i-check-whether-a-radio-button-is-selected-with-javascript)

Something like:

```
var counter = 0;
if(document.getElementById('id').checked) {
  counter++;
}else{
  counter--;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for it but i need it in svelte.js. kindly suggest the syntax for it .